# Redirect sterr in subshell to stdout in current shell in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, io-redirection, subshell

I have a subshell carrying out a function:

`local thing=$( doFunc )`

`doFunc` sends logging output to `stderr` (2) and '`thing`' gets assigned to `doFunc`'s output on `stdout` (1).

How can I run this line, but print `stderr` from the subshell to `stdout` in the current shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first make a copy of stdout on another FD, then redirect to that like

```
exec 3>&1
local thing=$(doFunc 2>&3)
```